# How to find out the parameters in an API using Python

Tags: python, json, api, parameters

Below is the code I have:

```
response = requests.get('https://website.com', headers= {'Authorization': 'key'})
```

The response I get is 200. So obviously that is good.

I am trying to pull data and format them into data frames afterwards. How do I move forward after this line of code? I don't know what parameters (I think that is the term) to put after because the vendor is very unresponsive and just gave me this link and key.

Is there a way to call for a list of the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas you can parse a json using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response)
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand once I start populating data into the console. But do you know how I can access that data with a token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Arthur there is a way to call an end point with multiple parameters

you could do like here by adding `params` option in your `requests` like

```
response = requests.get('https://website.com', params={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, headers= {'Authorization': 'key'})
```

then using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) you can get your dataFrame like

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json(), orient='columns')`

For your self-learn you can have a look at [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) it will help you handle any API call

and to setup your own API's [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is the good place to start if you love [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I find out what these parameters are though? The vendor has only provided a link and a key.

Comment: Normally it should give you the parameters and their types if the link has required params. maybe `Web Scraping` will help you to found the parameters

Comment: This is the link: https://support.safetyculture.com/integrations/getting-started-with-the-iauditor-api/ maybe you will have more experience than me in distinguishing next steps after I am able to connect.

Comment: @Arthur [this](https://developer.safetyculture.io/?_ga=2.92168412.774885275.1530120765-165333998.1530120765#introduction) is going to help you make any request on their API and you can found all the possible parameters. Hope it help you thanks.